# Show div with error message after submit

Tags: jsf, message

I have simple JSF login form which is redirecting if the user is successfully logged in. I would like not to display only a text if user can't log in, but a div with message. I would like to show that piece of html only if user enters wrong data and could not manage to log in.

How can i manage that? Can you please give me some example, both on form and backing bean with JSF?

I found much examples but only to display text (h:message). Those examples include already some html wrapper tags like div in which that text is wrapped. I would like to display div only if submit fails (it will fail if username/password are wrong).

Let me show this in simple html without JSF data how it looks:

```
        <div class="error">Username/password not correct!</div>

        <label for="user_name">Username:</label>
        <input name="user_name" type="text" id="user_name" maxlength="20"/>

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input name="password" type="password" id="password" maxlength="20"/>

        <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="log_btn" value="Login" />
```

So, I hope I am clear enough - I would like not to have that div container when this form is displayed on start, but would like to have that div container when user tries to submit and enters wrong data. I do not want error reports below every input, just that div with my custom single error message to appear.

Comment: I'm not sure. I do not know how to user h:message(s) with div wrapper added with message too. If h:message(s) can solve my problems, I'm all ear

Comment: I'm not sure BalusC. Unfortunetely I'm at my work and do not have my JSF project here (I'm working on it at home). I don't see where div element is inserted also with message? Should I write facesContext.addMessage("formid:inputid", facesMessage);

like

facesContext.addMessage("div_id:inputid", facesMessage);

<h:form id="div_id">
  <div class="error" id="inputid" />

I do not need <h:inputText>, i need basic div.

Is that way ok? No i need to include h:form tag?

Comment: How can I generate my own wanted element? Sometimes I want to display div or span, what is the way to display any html I want?

Comment: I tried to do:

<c:if test="${auth.success_status == 'error'}">
          <div class="error">Not correct!</div>
      </c:if>

But it's no good/partialy good with it because my Login class is SessionScoped and so when once auth.success_status gets "error" status there is no way back (example - you try to login, you get correct error div. But if user then writes same page to url again, error is set although it should not be.. How to avoid that Balus C?

Comment: I needed this: 

<h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{auth.success_status == 'error' and facesContext.postback}">
       <div class="error">Wrong username/pass</div>
      </h:panelGroup> 

So my problem was solved with this piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to do:  Not correct!  But it's no good/partialy
>   good with it because my Login class is SessionScoped and so when once
>   auth.success_status gets "error" status there is no way back (example
>   - you try to login, you get correct error div. But if user then writes same page to url again, error is set although it should not be.. How
>   to avoid that Balus C?

then let your bean be **viewScoped**  !

but the correct answer (as BalusC said) is using FacesMessages.

here is an example of how to use FacesMessages with CSS style Classes:

**JSF-XHTML:** i display the messages in **TABLE Layout**

```
<h:messages layout="table" showDetail="true" styleClass="FACES-MESSAGES" infoClass="MESSAGES-INFO" errorClass="MESSAGES-ERROR" warnClass="MESSAGES-WARN"/>
```

**in your bean:**

```
// FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN or FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO
FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "ERROR: ", "Invalid Data....");
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
```

**CSS:** for **TABLE Layout**

```
.FACES-MESSAGES {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: seperated;
    border: 0px solid #DDDDDD;
    margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;

}

.FACES-MESSAGES td{
    height: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;    
    font-size: 12px;    
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 22px;
}
.FACES-MESSAGES .MESSAGES-INFO{
    color: #0000DD;
    background: transparent url('images/message_info.png') 2px 0px no-repeat;

}

.FACES-MESSAGES .MESSAGES-ERROR{
    color: #BB0000;
    background: transparent url('images/message_error.png') 2px 0px no-repeat;

}
.FACES-MESSAGES .MESSAGES-WARN{
    color: #000;
    background: transparent url('images/message_warn.png') 2px 0px no-repeat;
}
```